# Adding dynamic variables to movieClip instance in Flash professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a number of instances of a movieClip on the stage in Flash. I would like to be able to add a dynamic variable to each. For example, I would like to number each instance.

I have tried giving each instance an instance name (eg. box1, box2) and writing the following code in the layer 1 > frame 1 code window

```
box1.number = 1;
box2.number = 2; etc.
```

or

```
box1["number"] = 1;
box2["number"] = 2;
```

but the variables are undefined when trying to access them in Flash builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a custom class for all your movieClips to extend  (use as a base class).  If you don't know how to do this, create the following MyCustomClassName.as file in the root of your .fla directory.

```
package {

    public class MyCustomClassName extends Sprite {  //use MovieClip is your box makes use of the timeline
        public var myNumber:int = 0;

        public function MyCustomClassName(num:int = 0) {
            myNumber = num;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your box object, right click it in the library and bring up the properties/linkage. Set the base class to the path to your custom class .as file

You can leave everything the same and now your boxes will inherit all properties and functions in that base class.

```
myBoxInstance.myNumber = 5;
```

OR if instantiating through code:

```
var box:MyCustomClassName = new MyCustomClassName(5);   //creates a new box giving it the number 5
```

Comment: So I would create a new movie clip for each box which would extend `MyCustomClassName`? How would I set `myNumber`?

Comment: Keep the same box you have now, just set it's base class to the custom class.  Then you can set the custom property like any other.  myBoxInstance.myNumber = 5;

Comment: If you box makes use of the timeline though, change extends Sprite to extends MovieClip in the class file

Comment: So to be clear, you only need one movieClip/Box, you create multiple instances of it and change the myNumber property for each.  If you're instanciating it through code, your could even use the number as an argument to the constructor. I'll update the code to show how

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble in that `myNumber` is always 0. `myNumber` is coming up on the auto-complete in Flash builder which is good, but my code in flash doesn't seem to work : `box1.myNumber = 1;`

Comment: how are you instantiating the objects?  by placing them on the timeline somewhere in flash?  or by code in flash builder?

Comment: I'm just dragging them onto the stage in Flash so I guess I'm adding them to the first frame on the timeline?

Comment: And where are setting the box1.myNumber = 1;  ?

Comment: I think in a code window labelled as being in scene, layer 1 : frame 1

Comment: Odd, you're not getting an error or warning when you run it?  It would probably be best set those variables on the same timeline where you put the instances

Comment: Nope I'm not getting any messages to my knowledge. I'm not sure what you mean by that last bit sorry. I seem to be working on a single timeline and on a single frame?

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work if I put the assignment code in the first frame of the timeline and if I use `goToAndStop(1)` in Flash builder.

Comment: Your timeline may be looping and destroying/creating new instances of your boxes - do you have more than one frame in your timeline?

Comment: I think I've discovered my mistake - thanks very much for all the help!. I was checking for `myNumber` before the frame had been drawn (in the same function that added the parent container to the display tree). I also only have one frame